# What causes the MS Windows 'System' Process to go nuts when compiling?

Tags: windows, crash

A couple of times recently I have noticed that 'something' is causing the Windows System Process to sit at 50+% and it will not quit until the PC is rebooted.  Happening on Win2k and Win XP so far.

This is particularly troublesome because it currently appears to be triggered by MSVC 2005/Incredibuild and rebooting the build servers is not a nice thing.

At the same time the 'System Idle Process' process is holding the rest of the CPU and the build steps themselves seem to be starved.  ie. a module that normally takes <5 minutes to compile is currently taking 20+.

I'd take a few guesses at maybe being virus checker or tortoise svn but would desperatly like some other suggestions.

Edit:
I've been experiencing this as something that is triggered, and the culprit may not be ongoing.  Thats not to say that some other ongoing process hasn't done something 'stupid' and is managing an active lock up of System while appearing to be idle itself.

System (100% of 1 core), and System Idle Process are sharing 98-100% of the total CPU. 
Occasionaly mt.exe, link.exe, buildservice would get a look in at 1-2%.
I'm running VNC to view the machine, so it's getting a look in on occasion.

Edit 2:
When left the previous evening the build process seemed to be progressing all be it slowly, but after waiting another 13 hours the 1 hour build process hasn't completed.  System is still hogging the 1 core.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that the "System" process is the time spent in the kernel (so performing disk I/O, network I/O (you did mention Incredibuild) and the like) -- I'd check for disk fragmentation, virus checkers and possibly look at these on other machines in your Incredibuild cluster.

As the System Idle process runs at "Low" priority, it's a red herring that it'd be "taking up CPU time" -- if anything it's just showing that there is available CPU time available. The fact the processing is stuck to a single processor shows that the process is doing something that is not multi-core aware, or someone has set it's thread affinity to 1.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed the virus checking software that I use can radically slow down compilation but it does not extend beyond the end of the build.  Turning off advanced and heuristic checking improves this to the extent that I do not have to disable the scanner entirely.  I have changed my scanning strategy such that I use scheduled full scans now more than advanced on the fly scanning, as it hurts the perfromance of a number of apps.  (n.b. I am using the latest cut of Kaspersky).  I'm also using an automated backup tool (AJCBackup) that also needs to be restrained when compiling.

You may also want to consider disableing the [Windows Indexing service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Indexing_Service) on drives that are be used to create a lot of temporary and object files, as it doesn't provide much value in this context for the amount of performance it draws.

Edit: Have checked which processes are actually hogging the CPU core and traced them back to a given app?

Comment: I am not familiar with any tools which will show which app is actually hogging the CPU.  I had just thought of sysinternals ProcessExplorer, but unsure how to get it to show such information.

Answer (score 0):

We've encountered issues with Kaspersky and Incredibuild in our offices - compiles and sometimes links will just hang and never finish.
Only seems to affect some machines though which is wierd, and only Windows XP (Vista seems immune from what I've seen).
Only solution I've found so far is to turn Kaspersky off entirely - so if you find a solution then let me know!

Answer (score 0):

RE: smacl, work from the Windows Search/Indexing Service (WSearch) won't be attributed to the System process's CPU time, it should come from the SearchIndexer.exe/SearchFilterHost.exe services (Vista+).

The majority of activity from System you will see will be in disk activity from the lazy writer and other disk accesses.  CPU activity from System will be because of kernel activity such as drivers ([ISRs/DPCs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms797921.aspx)) and other kernel-level filters (which *could* include AV file and process filters).

Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can aid in viewing CPU usage across processes, including System.  You can use the public [Microsoft Symbol Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy(VS.71).aspx) and [this resource](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/debugstart.mspx) to get you started.

If you can take a trace with Xperf (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/cc825801.aspx), I can help you analyze where the CPU time is being spent in the System (kernel) context.  Xperf isn't officially supported on XP, but you can [take a trace on XP and analyze it on other systems](http://blogs.msdn.com/pigscanfly/archive/2008/02/24/xperf-support-for-xp.aspx).

Xperf and Process Explorer should be able to shine a spotlight on exactly the module(s) that are causing the runaway CPU usage.  Symbols may not even be necessary to diagnose the problem; simply the module name can often point to the component in question that is slowing down your system.  For example, high CPU usage from ndis.sys can point to network interrupts, or activity from modules such as aavmker4.sys can point to AV software (Avast! in this case).

And as always, check if there are any updated drivers and AV software for your system.

Answer (score 0):

In my office, a conflict between Incredibuild and Spyware Doctor's Immunize feature caused similar issues.  Turning off Immunize solved it for us.

What anti-virus/malware do you use?

Comment: Was using entrust anti virus which we could not turn off even to test the theory :|  Maybe able to test this out as we run up a new clean PC before the anti virus goes on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same hangs when compiling using IncrediBuild in VS2003, on clean Windows 7 without any anti-virus. It worked fine on same box in XP and Vista.